How to configure laravel pint to use tabs instead of spaces when indenting
I can't find a fixer that i can configure to use tabs instead of spaces. Is there any work around for this in laravel/pint?
I've searched here in the fixers https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/ and did not find anything useful. There is the indentation_type but it is not  configurable to tabs, it is just set to either true or false.
